# Failed to Resolve third party libraries after install studio2.3

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

I have format my system two days back, and installed android studio 2.3, also i have defined proxy in File--> Settings by providing host,port,username and password. But still am facing gradle sync error : Failed to resolve libraries.

Please help me out to resolve this.

Is it necessary to use jdk 1.8 to achieve this?

[image: proxy setting]

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible that this proxy configuration is only for IJ (AS) itself and not working for Gradle. Try configuring the proxy in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` like described in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy.